# Get PocketQuery results to format the same as Jira

Tags: jira, confluence

I have a pocketquery that returns the issue text from Jira.  Any text mark-ups in the query results are printed literally.  For example, if I had a Jira issue "This is a Jira issue with **bold** text".   In Jira, the word 'formatted' gets displayed as bold font, but in the pocketquery results (displayed on a confluence page), it shows up as '**bold**'.   I think if it I used << bold >>bold<< /bold >> in the Jura issue, it wold display correctly on the confluence page, but then the html tag would show up in Jira.   Is there some sort of translator I can run the query results through, or something I can do with a template that will change the Jira mark-ups to html or css?

Comment: I see, you are slightly new on this site, you have to show us what you have tried, since it is written in Java, you have to show us what you have tried.

Comment: There is no Java involved